# AG-Grid display large number of rows fetched in multiple http requests

Tags: angular, ag-grid, infinite-scroll

I have a Ag-Grid that needs to display around 5000 rows that needs to be fetched from multiple http requests. The reason for this is the delay that occurs in fetching the data using HTTP requests. The idea is basically do an incremental upload of the grid so the user doesn't need to wait that full data is loaded. I saw the Ag-Grid has the infinite row model that works well for this purposes but the getRows() method is trigger only when the user scrolls down and in my case I would like that this method would be triggered automatically, in other words, that the full data would be loaded without the user has to scroll the grid down. Does anyone has any idea or suggestion how to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use ag-Grid's [transaction updates](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/data-update-transactions/) to update the row data as and when you retrieve data from api.

Comment: Thank you @ViqMontana and sorry for late reply! This is correct but in my case I have a different problem, I have long times fetching the data from Api, this is my problem. So I would like to implement the Infinite row model that automatically does incremental http requests but I would like to know a way to do this incremental http requests without the need to wait that user scrolls down the Grid.